# The method getCurrentSession() is undefined for the type SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing a web based project using Maven,Spring and Hibernate.I just have faced a problem. The problem is whenever I'm using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() it showing a error and the error is

> The method getCurrentSession() is undefined for the type SessionFactory

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.mahin.webchatapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebChatApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>WebChatApp</name>
  <description>For Chatting</description>

<properties>
  <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Java EE -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Others -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.32</version>
  </dependency>


</dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

  <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mahin"/>

  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webchatapp"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.mahin.models</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>

  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Here is the DAO class with problem:

```
package com.mahin.daos;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mahin.models.Users;

@Repository
public class usersDAO implements WebChatDAOs{

     @Autowired 
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     private Session getCurrentSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

    @Override
    public void addUser(Users user) {
        getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(Users user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Users getUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> getUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you import the wrong `SessionFactory`. Use:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
```

instead of:

```
import org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.SessionFactory;
```

Comment: Sorry,it's not helping.It is generating more errors.

Comment: If I import  SessionFactory in place of Session then there are four errors:

    1-The import org.hibernate.SessionFactory collides with another import statement

    2-The method getCurrentSession() from the type usersDAO refers to the missing type Session

    3-Session cannot be resolved to a type

    4-The method getCurrentSession() is undefined for the type SessionFactory

@BobTheBuilder

Comment: You need to import the correct SessionFactory. Not instead of Session, instead of the other SessionFactory.